# Python: displaying an image as a background process?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am using scikit-image, and the following shows what I'm doing, in an ipython console:

```
import skimage.io as io
import skimage.viewer.viewers.core as sv
im = io.imread('image.jpg')
sv.ImageViewer(im).show()
```

This works well, except that the viewer runs as a foreground process, which means that I can't access the ipython shell until I've closed the viewing window.  I like this viewer; for a grayscale image at least, the cursor shows the gray level and the indices of the current pixel.  But I would like to be able to both display the image, and to continue work in the console.  How can I best do this?

Comment: By the way, you can import ImageViewer straight from the skimage.viewer module.

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out!  Just need to do it in two stages (as per the documentation); first

```
from skimage.viewer import ImageViewer
```

and then

```
fs = ImageViewer(f)
fs.show()
```

This works fine (except for a blank figure window which is created with the `ImageViewer` command).

Answer (score 0):

Try launching IPython with:

```
ipython --gui=qt4
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try that the ImageViewer "show" method produces an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4.py", line 374, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt4agg.py", line 155, in draw
    self.update()
RuntimeError: underlying C/C++ object has been deleted